# Obtaining a non-rectangular dock area in Qt

Tags: qt

I am trying to achieve the below layout. Basically the idea is to achieve a non-rectangular dock area (in blue).

From my reading of the documentation in https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#details, under the arrangement of the `QMainWindow`, the `toolbar` always expands throughout the entire bottom of the `QMainWindow`.

Is there a way to obtain this non-rectangular layout?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for [`QMainWindow::setCorner`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCorner)?

Comment: ... and implementing the toolbar as a dock widget.